# Storing a Vector3 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vector, geolocation, coordinate

I typically store a physical vector position of the format `(x,y,z)` where each coordinate is a float, in a single column using varchar(250) or as three separate columns for each x, y, z components...

I'm wondering if there is a more suitable format for such vector structs for storing in MySQL? And, if so, would querying the data differ than the usual `SELECT vector_col from table`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a SET, though that is a text type so you'd need to parse the values back to floats. Probably wouldnt be as efficient as doing it your current triple column way.

[MYSQL SET data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html)